# Control the amount of filter using GPUImageLookUpFilter with a slider

Tags: gpuimage

I want to add a slider to control the amount of filter on images. Is it possible to be done with GPUImageLookUp Filter? or is there any other way to do that using GPUImage? Here is the code that applies the filter on the image:

```
NSString *filename = @"lookup.png";

GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:filename]];
GPUImageLookupFilter *lookupFilter = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];
[stillImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];
[lookupImageSource addTarget:lookupFilter];

[stillImageSource processImage];
[lookupImageSource processImage];
[lookupFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
filteredimage = [lookupFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want the `intensity` property of GPUImageLookupFilter. Varying it from 0.0 to 1.0 will change the degree to which the lookup is applied to your source image.